# CSS bug doubleclick changes text image and header background as well as font color

Tags: html, css

I don't want my html tags to change color and background when there is double click on it as you can see in this picture "Question" changes its color to white and background to blue when I doubeclicked on it. How I can solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're referring to is a css `::selection` attribute. The color isn't really changing, this is a native browser behavior to help users select and copy text. You can get rid of it but you must understand that you'll be breaking a very important usability pattern. People expect selection to work, even if it is stylized it should be there.

I would strongly advise you not to disable this behavior but customize it to fit your design if you really must.

```css
p::selection {
    color: red; 
    background: yellow;
}

div::selection {
    color: green; 
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<p>Questions that may already have your answer</p>

<div>Another option of text highlight</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply . It works but can we set different selection color for different elements or tags?

Comment: @AnkitaGabani of course, just use normal `css` selectors. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 2):

That's the default selection behavior for your browser. If you want to disable selection altogether you can use `user-select: none;` on your element.